# Multiplying doubles in kotlin (floating point error?)

Tags: kotlin

I'm using Kotlin 1.2, JVM target 1.8 on a Mac on Intellij IDEA 2018.2.

I am seeing very strange behavior when multiplying doubles with multiples of 9.[image]

For anybody who is curious, this result should be 1.35. This error happens without debugging as well, and is adding up for me over multiple runs. I can get around it by using 1.5*9 and then just dividing by 10, but does anybody know *why* this is happening?

Feel free to check out my sample on the [kotlin website](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/d6vmjtfshtfb9l3biga3ft4m3e/7g9d685bu6n066rl469iralqph)

Comment: Ah, so the idea is that floating point is inherently unstable after some amount of precision. I'll close this question out, I guess, but I'm about 80% sure I never saw this behavior in Java

Comment: Then you have just been lucky :)

Comment: try 0.15*9.0 in any languages and **print enough fractional digits** and you'll see. Most of the fractional values in decimal can't be represented exactly in binary floating-point types